# Perl as a batch-script tool - fully piping child processes?

Tags: perl, shell, batch-file, pipe

*Apologies if some of the terminology may be slighlty off here. Feel free to correct me if I use a wrong term for something.*

**Is it possible to use Perl as an "advanced shell" for running "batch" scripts? (on Windows)**

The problem I face when replacing a `.bat`/`.cmd` script that's getting too complicated with a perl script is that I can't easily run sub processes as a shell does.

That is, I would like to do the same thing from my perl script as a shell does when invoking a child process, that is, fully "connecting" STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR.

Example:

foo.bat -

```
@echo off
echo Hello, this is a simple script.
set PARAM_X=really-simple

:: The next line will allow me to simply "use" the tool on the shell I have open, 
:: that is STDOUT + STDERR of the tool are displayed on my STDOUT + STDERR and if
:: I enter something on the keyboard it is sent to the tools STDIN

interactive_commandline_tool.exe %PARAM_X%

echo The tool returned %ERROLEVEL%
```

However, I have no clue how to *fully* implement this in perl (is it possible at all?):

foo.pl -

```
print "Hello, this is a not so simple script.\n";
my $param_x = get_more_complicated_parameter();

# Magic: This sub executes the process and hooks up my STDIN/OUT/ERR and 
# returns the process error code when done
my $errlvl = run_executable("interactive_commandline_tool.exe", $param_x);
print "The tool returned $errlvl\n";
```

How can I achieve this in perl? I played around with [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm) but it seems this doesn't do the trick ...

Comment: What's wrong with good ol` [`system`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#system)? The new process should inherit your file descriptors, even on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this way:

```
print "Hello, this is a not so simple script.\n";
my $param_x = get_more_complicated_parameter();

system('cmd.exe', $param_x);
my $errorlevel = $? >> 8;
print "The tool returned $errorlevel\n";

sub get_more_complicated_parameter { 42 }
```

I don't have your interactive program, but the shell executed allowed me to enter commands, it has inherited environment defined in perl, etc.

I am using perl as replacement for more complicated shell scripts on Windows for long time and so far everything I needed was possible.

Comment: Oh my. Plain old `system` does indeed what I want. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you'll find [`IPC::Run3`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun3) useful. It allow you to capture both STDOUT and STDERR (but not pipe them in real time). Command error level will be returned in `$?`.